# How to fix cairo error in node.js app: Assertion failed: (angle_max >= angle_min)

Tags: node.js, svg, cairo, canvg, node-canvas

ERROR I GET:
Assertion failed: (angle_max >= angle_min), function _cairo_arc_in_direction, file cairo-arc.c, line 189.

With some svg icons my code works fine, but some of them cause issue (error above)

```
const svgContent = fs.readFileSync(`/path/to/svg`, 'utf8');
canvg(canvas, svgContent);
```

Comment: If those SVG files work everywhere else (eg in browsers), then report this bug to the Cairo folks.  Include the `<path>` that is causing the problem.  In the meantime you may be able to tweak your SVGs so that they work. But we can't help you that because we can't debug files we can't see.

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/issues/352

Answer (score 0):

This is [CVE-2019-6462](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-6462) in Cairo. If you're able to build Cairo from source, there's a patch available here: https://github.com/clearlinux-pkgs/cairo/blob/master/CVE-2019-6462.patch.